# How to read "protected" variable

Tags: php

i get a resultset from a class that manages WSDL Data.

I didn't write the code to the class, i only use it.

I call a function to create an ID with the service and want to work with that ID later in the same script.

My Resultset looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SaveResult Object
        (
            [id:protected] => newgeneratedID
            [success:protected] => 1
        )
)
```

So I tried $response[0]->id to get the ID i need.
Now I get a fatal error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property SaveResult::$id
```

I know it´s a noob question, but I don't get why I can print_r the object but not get the values inside.

Comment: Read this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any of protected data from another space except the same object.

But you can edit the SaveResult object and add getter for id:

```
public function getId() {
   return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: You would think this already existed. Having a class which holds data but offers no way to access it is pretty pointless.

Comment: *"You cannot use any of protected data from another space except the same object."* from the same class and any child class extending from it. Just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: @RichardA - yeah.. forget it.

Comment: @kmas Please more details. what you provide to `print_r()`?

Comment: @kmas He actually asket why it displays data, but he cannot get it. 
In `print_r`it will outputs like always. There are only case when it will not outputs - private static property.

Comment: I only provide the response you see in my first code snippet for print_r (So: print_r($response))

Comment: the best way i see is to add the function myself - thank you for all your great help even if it was a noob question for most of you :)

Answer (score 0):

There ought to be a method you can call in the `SaveResult` class which lets you access the data, something like:

```
$response[0]->getId();
```

See the documentation/source code of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a protected property with the ReflectionProperty interface.

The *HandyMan* component from the *phptoolcase library* has a handy method to read inaccessible objects properties.

```
$value = PtcHandyMan::getProperty( $your_object , 'propertyName');
```

Static property from a singleton class:

```
$value = PtcHandyMan::getProperty( 'myCLassName' , 'propertyName');
```

Very simple and usefull, though it is only adviced in few situations as protected/private properties are shouldn't be used outside of their scope.

You can find the *HandyMan* class here: http://phptoolcase.com/guides/ptc-hm-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Proper encapsulation is done by making the class's parameters private or protected as much as possible. You mitigate the fact that these parameters are now inaccessible from outside the class itself by making a 'get' function (getter) and 'set' function (setter) for each one, a la:

```
public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
```

I seem to understand the "SaveResult" class may contain this, but as I said, I can't find it.
However, this encapsulation also means that you cannot access the private/protected variables through any other means. `$response[0]->id` is impossible because the id is protected. So when trying to access the data, you use the getter on the array - as has been shown by others.

```
$response[0]->getId();

//or

foreach($array as $response) {
   echo $response->getId;
}
```